# How can I tweak Windows 7 or 8 to Utilize Multi Core Processors?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, performance, multi-core

Nowadays, desktop and workstations are getting more powerful as they have multi-core processors.

For the versions of Windows that support multi-core processors, do these versions actually utilize these multi-core processors or does the operating system just use 1 core at a single time?

How can I tweak Windows 7 or 8 to utilize multi-core processors?

Comment: depends which version of windows 7 and 8 you're talking about. Windows 7 Home, doesn't support multi-core cpu's

Comment: @Sickest So, can I assume that Windows 7 Starter, Windows 7 Home Basic, Windows 7 Home Premium and Windows 8 does not support multi-core. The rest of them (Windows 7 Professional, Windows 7 Enterprise, Windows 7 Ultimate, Windows 8 Pro, Windows 8 Enterprise) can support multi-core?

Comment: Also, can I assume that the 64-bits versions of the OS will be able to utilize the multi-core more efficient than the 32-bits version?

Comment: There are 2 different aspects you have to consider with a piece of software, just because it supports multi-cores, doesn't mean it utilizes it, which is why you have a good question. But if you're asking if a certain version of windows will run on windows os x, then you need to reword your question to ask one or the other or both, and I'm sure when of these guys is going to give you an awesome answer.

Comment: Again, you're question is way too broad, windows is going to run with or without multi core processing depending on the version of windows, BUT, are you going to get better performance because you're running on dual core or quad core, i don't know, and imo, i doubt it.

Comment: @Sickest So, can I assume that actually the user play the most important role in it because the user will need to know how to tweak in order to utilize the multi-cores even though the OS supports multi-cores?

Comment: not really, the software determines that, the user can't tweak anything in the software or in the computer built to help utilize the multi-cores. suggestion: read this: http://www.pcworld.com/article/221558/cpu.html

Comment: just reword this question instead of creating a whole new question with the edit button.

Comment: @Sickest, Yes, I wish I know how to reword this question. By the way, I have delete the new question. My objective for this question is to know if I can utilize multi-core features when running any application on the Windows OS (Windows 7 and Windows 8)

Comment: @Sickest You're confusing *physical* processors with logical processors. All Windows 7/8 editions supports multi-core processors out of the box, but only Professional editions or higher are licensed to use up to 2 physical processors. Talking about Windows 7, 32-bit editions are limited to 32 logical processors, and 64-bit editions are limited to 256. [Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/system-requirements)

Comment: true, i was trying to help him figure out what he was trying to ask anyway. wasn't attempting to answer it

Answer (score 1):

To put it short with the author's last question: Windows 7 or 8 will use all the cores. When you go to the task manager and see all those processes running, Windows has dibbied them up between the available cores. (The task manager's performance tab will show you that they're all doing something.)
Note that *one* of those processes can only be running on one core at any time. The exception to this rule is software specifically written to take advantage of multiple cores at the same time. These software programs are extremely complex. 
It's not up to Windows to decide if a certain process will use more than one core at a time - it's entirely the software's. A program that would greatly benefit from utilizing multiple cores at once would be converting video files or other CPU-intensive work. It can greatly reduce the time necessary to get the job done.

Comment: "For the versions of Windows that support multi-core processors, do these versions actually utilize these multi-core processors or does the operating system just use 1 core at a single time?" The confusion may arise from cores/actual CPUs. Win7 starter and home versions can only use 1 physical CPU (and all the cores inside of it). Win7 Pro, Ent, or Ultimate can use 2 physical CPUs (and all the cores inside of them - up to 32). See the bottom of http://windows.microsoft.com/systemrequirements

Answer (score 0):

Most of what the OS does is providing services for processes. Those processes call into the operating system from whatever cores they happen to be running on and the operating system generally provides that service by continuing to run on the same core. In addition, when the operating system has to dispatch later work, it does so using multiple cores.

This isn't a new feature. Modern multi-core machines are not all that different from older SMP machines that Windows has run on for years. Things like memory management and I/O were optimized because the Windows Server line would have been awful without it. Since Vista, Microsoft has worked significantly to improve the multi-core performance of features important to desktops such as graphics and sound processing.

So the short answer to your question is -- of course.